# Is it possible to factor $2A-P^{-1}AP$ into $A(2I-P^{-1}P)$ for $n\times n$ matrices $A, P$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a proof that a square $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is nilpotent iff $A$ is similar to $2A$. Assuming the latter, I get that for some $P$:

$$2A=P^{-1}AP $$

$$2A-P^{-1}AP = 0 $$

and from here I wish to factor as shown above to show that $A=0,$ so $A$ is nilpotent. This seems a bit iffy because $A$ is supposed to be any nilpotent matrix not just the $0$ matrix, so I'm not sure if my factoring step is valid. I'm also not sure if it matters that I get $A=0$ since I've already shown the forward direction for a general nilpotent matrix.

Comment: The factoring step is incorrect since there is no reason that $P^{-1}AP = AP^{-1}P$. (This is only valid if $A$ and $P$ commute, by the way)

Comment: To prove your statement, look at an eigenvalue of $A$, let's say $\lambda$. You can then prove that $2\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$, proving that $\lambda=0$ and $A$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has already been stated in a comment, this factorization is incorrect.

However, we can show that $A$ is nilpotent as follows. Suppose for the purpose of contradiction that $A$ has a non-zero eigenvalue. Suppose that $x \in \Bbb C^n$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with associated eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$. We have $Ax = \lambda x$. It follows that
$$
2A(P^{-1}x) = P^{-1}APP^{-1}x = P^{-1}Ax = \lambda P^{-1}x \iff\\
A(P^{-1}x) = (\lambda/2)P^{-1}x.
$$
That is, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then so is $\lambda/2$ (and the converse also holds). From that, we are forced to conclude that $\lambda/2^k$ is an eigenvalue for all integers $k$, which means that $A$ has infinitely many eigenvalues, which is impossible.

Thus, $A$ has $0$ as its only eigenvalue, which means that its characteristic polynomial is $p(x) = x^n$. By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $A$ must be nilpotent.

---

If you insist on a "vector-free" approach, here's another proof. Suppose for the purpose of contradiction that $\lambda \neq 0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. By the [Sylvester determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity), we have
$$
\begin{align}
0 &= \det(\lambda I - A) = \det(I - \lambda^{-1}A)
\\ & = \det(I - (\lambda^{-1}/2)P^{-1}AP)
= \det(I - (\lambda^{-1}/2) (AP)P^{-1}) = \det(2\lambda I - A).
\end{align}
$$
As before, we deduce that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ iff $2\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$.

---

Another approach, using the trace instead of the determinant. By taking the $k$th power of both sides of the equation $2A = P^{-1}AP$, we have
$$
2^kA^k = P^{-1}A^k P, \quad k = 1,2,3,\dots
$$
Taking the trace of both sides of the equation yields
$$
2^k\operatorname{tr}(A^k) = \operatorname{tr}(A^k) \implies \operatorname{tr}(A^k) = 0, \quad k = 1,2,3,\dots.
$$
In other words, $\lambda_1^k + \cdots + \lambda_n^k = 0$ for all positive integers $k$ (where $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$). Using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Application_to_the_characteristic_polynomial_of_a_matrix), we can conclude that $A$ must have $0$ as its only eigenvalue.

---

Note that it is possible for this equation to hold when $A$ is an arbitrary linear operator. For example, let $A$ denote the derivative operator over the vector space of smooth functions over $\Bbb R$. Let $P$ denote the operator $f(x) \mapsto f(2x)$. We find that
$$
[P^{-1}AP] f(x) = [P^{-1}A]f(2x) = P^{-1} \frac d{dx}f(2x) = P^{-1} 2f'(2x) = 2f'(x) = 2Af(x).
$$
So, it indeed holds that $P^{-1}AP = 2A$.

Notably, every $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Typo in the `trace` approach: the 2 needs to be raised to the $k^{th}$ power too.

Comment: @NickD Good catch